# Отличие ActionLink от RouteLink

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

В чём отличие `Html.ActionLink` и `Html.RouteLink`?

Вопрос возник в связи с тем, что прочитал, мол якобы `Html.RouteLink` помогает выбрать конкретный маршрут из набора маршрутов при генерации ссылки. Однако, я так и не понял как это сделать да и вообще `Html.ActionLink` и так выбирает подходящий по сигнатуре маршрут. Тогда в чем смысл `Html.RouteLink` не пойму. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Вот есть код, почему две ссылки ведут на одинаковый контроллер и действие если указаны разные роуты

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "D1",
                url: "{controller}/{action}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
            );
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "D2",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Zurab", action = "Pavel" }
            );
```

Ссылки

```
@Html.RouteLink("Click", "D2", new { id = 14 })
        @Html.ActionLink("Click", "Index")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод ActionLink принимает имя контроллера и экшена и использует эти параметры для поиска подходящего элемента в таблице роутинга. При этом, подходящей считается первая запись, удовлетворяющая условиям поиска (совпадение контроллера и экшена). Соответственно, если в приложении сложный роутинг, то ActionLink может работать дольше, чем RouteLink. При изменении таблицы роутинга (и даже при изменении порядка записей) может нарушиться работа ранее написанных вызовов ActionLink.

Метод RouteLink использует имя объекта route для поиска в таблице. Соответственно, порядок добавления записей в таблицу роутинга не имеет значения, и изменения/добавление роутов не нарушит работу RouteLink. Также, RouteLink предоставляет бОльшую точность в выборе роута, что особенно полезно когда ActionLink может вызвать некоторую неоднозначность. Например, может быть несколько роутов для одного контроллера и экшена. Тогда ActionLink будет всегда возвращать первый роут, а с помощью RouteLink можно указать конкретный route.